# How to exclude environment files when publishing an NPM package

Tags: node.js, npm

I've signed up for private packages with npmjs.org so that I can re-use my own node.js code in other projects more easily. I want to publish a project, but I don't want my .env file to be stored online. Is there a way to exclude certain files from being uploaded when I publish?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add them to `.npmignore`

https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/developers#keeping-files-out-of-your-package

```
# .npmignore
.env
```

Note that this is separate from `.gitignore`. `npm` can still publish files that are `.gitignore`d. In fact this is pretty common since you might do a build step and have `.npmignore src` and `.gitignore dist` and publish `dist`.