# Adding process.env secrets to a NPM package

Tags: npm, environment-variables

I am currently building a NPM package but has encountered an error. I have declared secret variables in my code, (which yes, of course is in .gitignore).

Without the env variables, the code won't work properly. But I don't know how to keep the env secret while trying to publish it in NPM.

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49136072/how-to-exclude-environment-files-when-publishing-an-npm-package#:~:text=Add%20them%20to%20.npmignore) answer your question?

Comment: Nope, it doesn't. What I am trying to ask is: the env file is in the package so the code actually works, but nobody can view it.

The link you have given me asks how to exclude it in the package, not include it but make it secret.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you publish an NPM package the code will be made public on https://www.npmjs.com/ so there is no way to use secrets in the manner you want.

It sounds like an anti-pattern if your package is only usable with secrets
provided by the author. Normally you would allow consumers to provide their own secrets via env variables or function calls. Instead your readme should contain a description of how the consumer can provide the secret when using your package, like setting an environment variable.

Answer (score 0):

This is impossible for a very simple reason:

Anything that is running on user's computer is accessible to the user. It does not matter how your variable is delivered to your code; if it ends up in a variable, then it ends up somewhere in memory. The user can inspect the memory and thus get the value of that variable. The user can inspect all the hard drive contents, all network traffic, etc. So you can not have secrets on user's computer at all.